# Handling groups of key, value pairs while parsing lxc container file with python

Tags: parsing, python-2.7, lxc

I have lxc configuration file looking like ini/prop file but it contains duplicate key-value pairs that i need to group, I wish to convert in dict and json, here is the sample:

```
lxc.tty = 4
lxc.pts = 1024
lxc.rootfs = /opt/mail0/rootfs/
lxc.network.type = veth
lxc.network.name = eth7
lxc.network.link = br7
lxc.network.ipv4 = 192.168.144.215/24
lxc.network.type = veth
lxc.network.name = eth9
lxc.network.link = br9
lxc.network.ipv4 = 10.10.9.215/24
```

here is desired python data, that also converts keys from cfg to key paths

```
data = {
"lxc":{ "tty": 4, "pts": 1024 , "rootfs": "/opt/mail0/rootfs",
    "network": [
     {"type": "veth", "name": "eth7", "link": "br7", "ipv4":"192.168.144.215/24"},
     {"type": "veth", "name": "eth9", "link": "br9", "ipv4":"10.10.9.215/24"}
    ]
  }
}
```

Can you share/suggest your method & rules for handling such key, value pairs groups. Thank you in advance!